# How to let TortoiseHg (Mercurial) on Windows use the Private Key file generated (by Puttygen)?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, tortoisehg, public-key

I have used Puttygen to create a public and a private key, and then is ready to let TortoiseHg on Windows 7 do a clone by going to

```
ssh://somebody@code.somewhere.com/somecode
```

but there seems to be no where to add the private key to TortoiseHg?  (or even just the mercurial command line)

The file is already some where on hard disk as somefile.ppk   Does someone know how to add it?

Comment: This question is duplicated on SuperUser: http://serverfault.com/questions/147136/how-to-let-tortoisehg-mercurial-on-windows-use-the-private-key-file-generated/147388  I think it belong there instead of StackOverflow since it is not related to programming, but to software in general.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Either add the following to the [ui]-section of the mercurial.ini in your home directory (assuming your key is in "C:\Users\UserName\mykey.ppk"):

```
[ui]
ssh = tortoiseplink.exe -ssh -i "C:\Users\UserName\mykey.ppk"
```

or use Pageant, found in the TortoiseHg installation path (e.g. C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\Pageant.exe). Start it, double click the taskbar-icon that appears, and add the .ppk-file.

Comment: i see. thanks.  i may add here that the "home directory" on Windows 7 is something like c:\users\peter

Comment: Note that if you want to specify your username, that can be done with the -l switch for tortoiseplink (add "-l myusername" to this ssh-line)

Comment: Thanks, this approach can also be used for CCnet build server, just put it in the service accounts home directory

Comment: @HoangTran Use `-pw password` argument to login with the specified password.

Comment: @david.s Thanks, but that means password is put in this plaintext .ini file, what I look for is a way to save it securely.

Comment: Starting in TortoiseHg 3.5, `tortoiseplink` isn't added to the PATH by default, so you need to do `ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\Users\UserName\mykey.ppk"` instead

Comment: Also, you may not have tortiseplink.exe installed by default; that was the next prob for me.

Answer (score 0):

need an ssh key generator first

1. cmd: ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. open PuTTY Key Generator
3. Conversions >  import key: open the id_rsa file in C:\Users\.ssh   (you may have to create the folder !must run cmd as Admin!)
4. Save the imported file id_rsa as id_rsa.ppk
5. Open Pageant.exe in TortoiseHG folder
6. It will show up in Taskbar
7. Right click and click add keys
8. Finally add your new ppk file

Oh right copy the contents of id_rsa.pub to hg host