# Remove a key from Pageant using the Pageant command line

Tags: command-line-arguments, putty, ssh-keys, pageant

I used Pageant to add keys to it from a C# code behind. I found that I can use the command line to add keys to Pageant described here:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-cmdline

It works fine, but I start thinking how can I remove a key from Pageant using the command line client? Is there any way to remove them somehow? After a while I have a lot of loaded keys from different users and I think that is the reason why the authentication method doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to remove keys from Pageant using a command-line.

This [used to be on a wishlist](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty-wishlist.git;a=blob;f=data/pageant-key-mgmt;h=41529f00235eecaf26792463d6b5bbb5e3c6bd88;hb=ae53f81472e430b4d044cd55dbcfdc5c15caa021):

> We can already add keys to the primary Pageant,
>   but **it might be good to be able to delete keys** or shut it down as
>   well.

But [it's not anymore](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty-wishlist.git;a=commit;h=7933b28fdb8a579b467d99e61a20a2e38d13c5cb).

---

Also the only way to add key to Pageant automatically is to have the key unencrypted. What defies a purpose of Pageant.

So, I do not see a point of this. Why don't you use the key directly?
Do you use some SSH client/library that does not allow using key directly, but supports Pageant?

Anyway, you may kill Pageant and (re)load some keys.

Comment: Yes, I want to push to a Bitbucket repository, using an SSH URL, that's why I need the Pageant.

Comment: See [How do I tell Git for Windows where to find my private RSA key?](http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key)

Comment: Thank you very much! But in case of Mercurial, if I delete the private key files there are still on the Pageant Key List. Yes, I can kill Pageant and after a restart, the list is empty, but I think this isn't the more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: I never used Mercurial. But even with Mercurial there has to be a way to use private key file directly, without Pageant. See for example [How to let TortoiseHg (Mercurial) on Windows use the Private Key file generated (by Puttygen)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951011/how-to-let-tortoisehg-mercurial-on-windows-use-the-private-key-file-generated)

Comment: The wishlist link is broken.

Comment: @Jeremy True. It was removed from the wishlist. I've fixed the links.