# how to give mercurial access through PPK key

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, putty

When I try to clone the project on a formatted computer  I get an error because I don't have access permission to the repositories. I try to clone to project using net beans "clone other" option. The problem arrises from the fact that the users involved in the project don't remeber how to process to grant permission was done. I know that the permission is given using a ppk file somehow. but I don't remeber how. I have the ppk from the old formatting.

Comment: I added the `putty` tag to your question, because I assume "_ppk file_" refers to a PuTTY PPK keyfile for SSH connections. Feel free to remove that tag if I am wrong (with my apologies).

Comment: May be related: [How to let TortoiseHg (Mercurial) on Windows use the Private Key file generated (by Puttygen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2951011/12567365)